# Backbone Marionette, Render Region if not already rendered

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

So I want to render a sidemenu itemview only if it's not rendered already. This is so unessecary I don't force unessecary re-rendering.

I have figured a solution to render a view if not rendered in a region already.

Take the following example in a controller object called by a router.:

```
Admin.showIndex= function(){
    if (!MyApp.layout.sidepanel.currentView || !(MyApp.layout.sidepanel.currentView instanceof AdminSidePanel)){
        MyApp.layout.sidepanel.show(new AdminSidePanel());
    }else{
        alert("Already rendered sidepanel!");
    }
    // More stuff!
}
```

Is this a good way to do it? It works like this:

- If I F5 refresh the page /#admin , the sidepanel is rendered.
- If I go in forexample /#admin/submenu and back to #admin, sidepanel is not rendered again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks good to me. I've used similar logic in my project.

I prefer this approach over explicitly maintaining a global state variable in `MyApp`.